# MYSQL - Two tables get record from second table last tracked row for each user

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables

Table A has `usr_id , usr_name , usr_status [1 or 0]`

Table B has `id, usr_id,tracked_date [Each user can track multiple time]`

Need to get the last track of each user has `usr_status = 1`

How to achieve through MySQL query?

Tried like:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tableb b
        LEFT JOIN
    tablea a ON a.usr_id = b.usr_id
GROUP BY a.usr_id
```

Please advice ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In a Derived table, get the maximum value of `tracked_date` for every `usr_id`
- Join this result-set back to the main tables, to get the corresponding row(s).

Try:

```
SELECT 
  ta.*, tb.* 
FROM 
  tablea AS ta 
JOIN tableb AS tb 
  ON tb.user_id = ta.usr_id 
JOIN (
      SELECT 
        user_id, 
        MAX(tracked_date) AS max_tracked_date 
      FROM tableb
      GROUP BY user_id
     ) AS dt 
  ON dt.usr_id = tb.usr_id AND 
     dt.max_tracked_date = tb.tracked_date 
WHERE ta.usr_status = 1
```

---

In MySQL version (8.0.2 and above), we can use [Window Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html). Using `Row_Number()` we can set row number to 1 for the row with highest `tracked_date` value, in a partition of `usr_id`. Now, we can use this as a Derived Table and consider only those rows where row number is equal to 1.

```
SELECT 
  dt.* 
FROM 
(
  SELECT
    ta.*, 
    tb.*, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ta.usr_id 
                       ORDER BY tb.tracked_date DESC) AS row_no 
  FROM 
    tablea AS ta 
  JOIN tableb AS tb ON tb.usr_id = ta.usr_id 
  WHERE ta.usr_status = 1
) AS dt 
WHERE dt.row_no = 1
```

---

**Additional:** If you are looking to get all users (`status = 1`), but no `tracked_date` entry yet; a straight `LEFT JOIN` will not work between the tables and the Derived Table.

We will have to first get the **complete** row corresponding to maximum `tracked_date` in a separate Derived Table; and then do a `LEFT JOIN` from the users table, to get all users.

```
SELECT
ta.*, dt2.* 
FROM
  tablea AS ta
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT tb.*, 
        dt.max_tracked_date
 FROM tableb AS tb
 JOIN (
       SELECT
         usr_id,
         MAX(tracked_date) AS max_tracked_date
       FROM tableb
       GROUP BY usr_id
      ) AS dt
   ON (dt.usr_id = tb.usr_id AND
       dt.max_tracked_date = tb.tracked_date) 
) AS dt2 ON ta.usr_id = dt2.usr_id  
WHERE ta.usr_status = 1
```

**RESULT**

```
| usr_id | usr_name | usr_status | id  | usr_id | stage | tracked_date        | max_tracked_date    |
| ------ | -------- | ---------- | --- | ------ | ----- | ------------------- | ------------------- |
| 1      | john     | 1          | 2   | 1      | 2     | 2018-11-12 13:12:12 | 2018-11-12 13:12:12 |
| 2      | dave     | 1          | 3   | 2      | 1     | 2018-11-12 13:12:12 | 2018-11-12 13:12:12 |
| 3      | smith    | 1          |     |        |       |                     |                     |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/veuz8gyMAT4NvvJ9eaADwS/2)

Comment: @vignesh.D happy to help :) By the way, if you can use MySQL version 8.0.2 and above, there is less verbose query available using Window functions.

Comment: Ok .. Thank you :)

Comment: Works fine but it wont show user who dont have tracks , also need to show users dont have tracks list

Comment: @vignesh.D change all `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN` to get users (even without tracks list).

Comment: Tried , but still same result @madhur

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183561/discussion-between-madhur-bhaiya-and-vignesh-d).

Comment: @vignesh.D in case of needing all users, straight Left join does not work. check this fiddle for the solution in that case: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/veuz8gyMAT4NvvJ9eaADwS/2